# Could not create new simulator as updating Xcode to 8.3.3 removed all of my simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

[image]

On tap create button nothing gone a changed.

Any solution for this ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Re-install Xcode?

Comment: I had installed from the app store just 2 days ago.

Comment: I'm having the same problem today... I know it is an old version of xcode but I have to compile and try an old App :/